# Paypal PDT Error 4002

Tags: php, paypal, eclipse-pdt, worldpay

I am integrating Paypal into a website via Worldpay's APM payment API.

I have enabled PDT on my paypal sandbox and am using Paypal's PHP example code from their github repo to retrieve the data, however every call I do to verify the transaction via PDT returns FAIL Error: 4002.

This appears to be a generic error message and the solutions on the paypal developer website has not helped me to resolve the problem.

I also found a question from this site (in 2015) which suggested uppercase-ing the tx code. This has not helped either.

Does anyone have experience verifying with PDT while using Worldpay who has resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In this case it appears that Worldpay's simulator is not compatible with the Paypal sandbox, therefore no payments are going to Paypal.